# What determines the type of a grid column in a Telerik MVC grid?

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

My column is defined as follows:

> columns.Bound(o => o.SequenceNumber).Title("Seq #").Width(50).ClientTemplate("' value='<#=SequenceNumber#>' />");

The model I'm pulling in has *SequenceNumber* defined as `Nullable<decimal>`. When I pull in the grid's properties, the `Type` is "Number". Normally, this is referring to integers in our program. I know that "Decimal" is a valid value for the `Type`. How do I get my datacolumn to show up as that `Type`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, my solution is to manually change the data type for the column for this grid as it is retrieved for export, as my attempts to suggest a datatype failed.

Answer (score 1):

The Telerik controls do some basic reflection to match up an appropriate editor. `Nullable<decimal>` doesn't appear to match the numeric editor though (tested v2015.1.318).

Instead, you'll want to provide more general attributes that it knows to check for:

```
// This assumes you have the editor templates added
// to your  ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder.
[UIHint("Number")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "0.00")]
public Nullable<decimal> SequenceNumber { get; set; }
```

You can also use [DataType] as well for currency types.

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public Nullable<decimal> Amount{ get; set; }
```

Edit -

Tested another method by adding a new EditorTemplate called `Decimal.cshtml` into ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates:

```
@model decimal?
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m))
```

The grid finds this as expected with no additional attributes on SequenceNumber.

Comment: I have tried all three of these. I'm still getting the Number datatype.